# Can I create a new suite within a @Factory in TestNG?

Tags: testng

I have a class with TestNG annotations which runs functional tests on a website, I first define a Browser class - simple POJO:

```
class Browser {
   private String browserName;
   private String browserVersion;
   private String platform;

...getters and setters and constructor...
}
```

and now the TestNG annotated class itself:

```
class BrowserTest {

public BrowserTest(Browser b) {
    ...
    create browser session, etc. (uses Selenium Grid underneath)
    ...
}

@Test
public void login() {
    ...test login...
}

@Test
public void logout() {
    ...test logout...
}

@Factory
public Object[] create() throws Exception {

    List<Object> testList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Browser[] browsers = {
        new Browser("google-chrome", "", ""),
        new Browser("firefox", "", ""),
        new Browser("internet-explorer", "9", ""),
    };

    //Create new instance of this class for each browser

    for (Browser b: browsers) {
        testList.add(new BrowserTest(b));
    }

    return testList.toArray();

    }
}
```

the @Factory method above works well and I create multiple instances of the BrowserTest classes each of them initialized with a different browser which TestNG will run within the same suite that contained the first instance of BrowserTest.

I'd like to know if it is possible to create a new suite for each new class instance or better yet if TestNG provides a top-level mechanism to manipulate objects at the suite level (afaik the @Factory method only works at the class level) - so I could programmatically create new suite instances each of them initialized to use a different browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Factory` only works at the test level, so the answer to your question is no.

However, you can create new suites with TestNG's XML API, which works at a higher level by creating in-memory versions of your testng.xml file. Look up the `XmlSuite`, `XmlTest`, etc... classes. If you go that route, you probably no longer need a `@Factory` at all since you can instantiate the test classes directly and then include them in a `<test>` tag created with XmlTest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Cedric. I also tried to modify the suite via the ISuite interface passed on the ISuiteListener listener to no avail. Looking forward if you decide to incorporate some functionality in TestNG to iterate a suite with a number of parameters in the testng.xml XML file itself.

Comment: Correct, objects passed to listeners are expected to be read-only, although some modifications on them happen to work. Feel free to email your proposal to testng-users, we can take it from there.